# A block in motion explodes

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, momentum

> A 9.5 kg block (A) is traveling in the positive x-direction with a speed of 3.0 m/s. At some point, it explodes and breaks into two pieces. After the explosion, block C, which is 6.0 kg, moves off in the negative y-direction, and block B, which is 3.5 kg, moves off at an angle 35° with respect to the x axis.

[image: sorry for the crappy recreation]

The two parts of this question that I am stuck on are:

> **a)** find the momentum of the 2-block combination after the explosion and write it in vector notation

- Here I know that momentum is conserved, so Pa = Pbc = 28.5 kg*m/s
- I am confused about how to separate the x and y components of the momentum after the explosion: can I use trigonometry with the mass of block B as the hypotenuse?

> **b)** Find the speeds of blocks B and C after the explosion

- Since momentum is conserved, and Mass(A) = Mass(B)+ Mass(C), I know that V(A)=V(B)+V(C), but I don't understand how to split them (I know it's not in half...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the right ideas, but you don't dare to put them in maths ! Momentum conservation is vectorial. Here, you have a 2D system, so let's write it with 2 component vectors.

I will denote $\vec{P}_{i/f}$ the initial and final momentum respectively.

So the momentum conservation yields

$ \vec{P}_i = \vec{P}_f  $

I choose to represent the $x$-axis as the first component of my vector, and $y$ the second one. Thus,

$\begin{pmatrix} M_aV_a \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} M_bVb_x + M_cVc_x \\ M_bVb_y + McVc_y \end{pmatrix} \quad \quad \quad (1)$

Now the exercise tells you several things. First of all, you know $M_a,V_a,M_b$ and the angle at which block $B$ takes off. You have to trigonometrically decompose the speeds to find out how to write them in vector form. For instance, $Vb_x = V_B\cdot\cos(35)$, and $Vb_y = Vb\cdot\sin(35)$. With the same reasoning, $Vc_x = 0$ and $Vc_y = Vc$

Because of momentum conservation being vectorial, momentum is conserved on the $x$-axis as well as the $y$-axis independently. From (1), you see that

$\left\{ \begin{array}{l} M_aV_a = M_bV_b\cdot\cos(35) \\ 0 = MbV_b\sin(35) + M_cV_c \end{array} \right.$

The only unknowns are $V_b$ and $V_c$. All you need to do is solve this equation system.

Comment: Gotcha! Thanks! I wasn't thinking of the momentum as being conserved in each component separately.

Answer (score 0):

Momentum conservation says $\vec{p}_A = \vec{p}_B + \vec{p}_C$, we can split this in components:

$$p_{A,x} = p_{B,x} + p_{C,x} \\
p_{A,y} = p_{B,y} + p_{C,y}$$

Some of these momentums are $0$. Which one?

For the block B - the only one with a motion not parallel to one of the axes' - you have to use trigonometry.

To get the velocity, once you have the momentum, should be straight forward, since $\vec{p} = m \cdot \vec{v}$.